# Wrong/Switching rendering order in d3js (v4)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have a weird behavior with a simple pie chart nested in an Angular (v1) App.

```
d3Service.then(function(d3){ // angular service wrapper for d3
    var pieVm = scope.pie;
    var radius = pieVm.d3.baseWidth/2;
    pieVm.d3.chart = d3.select('#container')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 '+pieVm.d3.baseWidth+' '+pieVm.d3.baseHeight);

    // set container to the middle
    pieVm.d3.container = pieVm.d3.chart.append('g')
        .attr('width', pieVm.d3.baseWidth)
        .attr('height', pieVm.d3.baseHeight)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + ", " + radius + ")");

    pieVm.d3.outerArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(35)
        .outerRadius(50 - pieVm.d3.space)
        .padAngle(pieVm.d3.space * Math.PI / 180);

    pieVm.d3.arcs = d3.pie()
        .value(function(d) {return d.value;})
        .startAngle(pieVm.d3.startAngle - pieVm.d3.space * Math.PI / 180)
        .endAngle(pieVm.d3.endAngle + pieVm.d3.space * Math.PI / 180);
});
```

After the data is loaded (async with a REST service) the render method is called

```
function _loadData() {
    dataService.loadData(pieVm.someArg).then(function (response) {
        pieVm.data = response;
        // a timeout seems to helpl a bit?
        $timeout(_doReRender);
        return response;
    });
}

function _doReRender() {
    d3Service.then(function (d3) {
        var paths = pieVm.d3.container.selectAll('path')
            .data(pieVm.d3.arcs(pieVm.data.entries), function(d, i){ console.log(d.index, i); return d.data.id; });

        paths.enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('fill', '#009898')
            .each(function(d){
                this._current = d;
            })
            .attr('d', pieVm.d3.outerArc)
            .merge(paths)
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween('d', arcTween)


        paths.exit().remove();
    });
}
```

As you can see I log `d.index` and `i` in the key function of the `.data` call. What I actually see when switching data is the following:

```
0 1
1 0
2 2 
3 3
```

After switching data again

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

Somehow the computed index `d.index` and the actual index `i` randomly missmatch. The actual problem seems to be that those are mixed (sometimes they are switched, sometimes not). The transition only looks as expected when the order remains the same between two data loadings (either `1 0` and `0 1` or `0 0` and `1 1`). If they are not the same the paths 0 and 1 will switch positions which is not the desired behavior. Additionally this bahvior is completly random. Without reloading the page i can switch between the data sets 10 times and it's gonna look like expected about 3 or 4 times and 6 or 7 times the first elements switch positions.
Any ideas, what's actually going on?

/edit
for testing I added some simple data sets (same behavior):

```
var sets = [
    [{id: "v01", value: 14}, {id: "v02", value: 10}, {id: "v03", value: 12}],
    [{id: "v01", value: 7}, {id: "v02", value: 20}, {id: "v03", value: 7}],
    [{id: "v01", value: 15}, {id: "v02", value: 18}]
];
var i  = 0;
$interval(function(){
    pieVm.data.entries = sets[i%sets.length];
    $timeout(_doReRender);
    i++;
}, 2500);
```

Comment: indeed. the error, how ever, only occurs when the mismatch is mixed between different data-sets. added data arrays in /edit

Comment: `d.index` is calculated by d3 (otherwise it would be `d.data.index`). I think I found the problem: adding a comparator to the pie function with `.sort(function() { return -1; }` seems to solve the problem. How ever, I still don't understand the random bahvior

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour with that data you pasted.